# AWS Athena not recognizing date functions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

```
STR_TO_DATE(string_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > (select timestamp from table)
```

this line causes the error 'Function str_to_date not registered' in Athena. is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: could you provide example data you try to convert and the whole query?

Comment: See https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html for what's currently available in Athena.

Answer (score 1):

All databases have their own set of functions, even though some are common and exist in more than one. `STR_TO_DATE` is not available in Athena, but there are lots of other date and time functions that can be used to achieve the same goal.

You can find links to all functions supported by Athena here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html

In your case I think you can use either [`parse_datetime`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime), which looks like it works like `STR_TO_DATE` in your example.

Alternatively I think you could cast the string to a timestamp since the format you are using matches Athena's, try `CAST(string_time AS TIMESTAMP)`